# htmlpurifier remove inline css

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am using htmlpurifier to clean up user content. I am trying to remove inline style attributes like

```
<div style="float:left">some text</div>
```

I want to remove the whole style attribute.

How to do it using htmlpurifier?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can tweak the [AllowedProperties](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#CSS.AllowedProperties) configuration by passing it an array of **valid** css attributes that should not be removed (white-list approach).

However, the following should remove all css attributes

```
$config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', array());
```

See this [online demo of purifying your input html](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BCSS.AllowedProperties%5D=&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BNull_HTML.Allowed%5D=1&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=%3Cdiv+style%3D%22float%3Aleft%22%3Esome+text%3C%2Fdiv%3E&submit=Submit)

Comment: Thanks again! cute solution)