# How can I safely allow a limited subset of HTML tags in a user-supplied string?

Tags: php

I am using an wysiwyg editor (ckeditor) and I need to allow users to use these tags:

```
a (with only `rel=nofollow`), ul, ol, li, p, strong, br
```

and I need also to avoid inserting css or js or other stuff that can compromise the website.

`strip_tags` doesn't work because it allow css - for example this must NOT work:

```
<p style="margin:1000px;"> hello </p>
```

Comment: [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: I prefer to avoid using external libraries :)

Comment: @xRobot Then you're **doing it wrong**. That is the most backwards attitude imaginable, and the worst attitude for a programmer to have.

Comment: @xRobot why not external libraries?

Comment: The use PHP's DomDocument and remove unwanted tags/attributes yourself

Comment: @xRobot — Feel free to build your own HTML parser based white list filter. See you in a few years (when we'll point out the bugs in it).

Comment: The reason for using a library, @xRobot, is that someone else has already done the work, discovered the bugs, etc. If there's a licensing issue, then I can understand your aversion better.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes though. It's a reasonable and clearly stated question that shows some research as well.

Comment: but html purifier doesn't remove css

Comment: It appears that it does: look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881125/htmlpurifier-remove-inline-css). I'll admit that I don't know much about HTML Purifier (I haven't used it in a project), so I'm not sure what else it can do.

Comment: html purifier also add rel=nofollow ?

Comment: @xRobot there is allowedAttributes config option where you specify the attributes you wish to allow

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is a standards-compliant HTML filter library written in PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive whitelist, it will also make sure your documents are standards compliant, something only achievable with a comprehensive knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for allowing only particular tags.

```
<?php
    $text = '<p>Test <span>paragraph</span>.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
    echo strip_tags($text);
    echo "\n";

    // Allow <p> and <a>
    echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

The above will output:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

---

**Workaround for CSS**

```
//strip out inline css and simplify style tags 
$search = array('#<(strong|b)[^>]*>(.*?)</(strong|b)>#isu', '#<(em|i)[^>]*>(.*?)</(em|i)>#isu', '#<u[^>]*>(.*?)</u>#isu');
```

`strip_tags` has doesn't recognize that css within the style tags are not document text. To fix this do something similar to the following:

```
$htmlstring = preg_replace("'<style[^>]*>.*</style>'siU",'',$htmlstring);
```

Comment: "strip_tags doesn't work because it allow css"

Comment: did you see "strip_tags doesn't work because it allow css - for example this must NOT work" in OPs quiestion?

Comment: @eis There's a work-around for this.

Comment: @meagar I added the work-around.

Comment: You missed the point completely. This still doesn't help filter out `<p style="color:red">`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar OP described the problem so that `<p style="margin:1000px;"> hello </p>` should not work, but `<p>hello</p>` should. I don't see that in your answer at all?

Comment: Lemme think of another code. :)

Comment: Stop thinking of code. Your answer of `strip_tags` will *remain* wrong, no matter how much you cobble onto it. This is a solved problem, and suggesting code snippets to "fix" the problem is just making your answer *more incorrect*. You shouldn't be attempting to solve this *extremely* difficult problem with regular expressions. You're just introducing subtler security problems.

Comment: So, what should I do now, @meagar?